# how to differential exponential of a matrix variable $f(X)=e^{X(t)\mathrm{d}t}$?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, matrix-equations

I have a function about a square matrix $X$ which depends also time: $f(X)=e^{X(t)}$, $t$ is time. So how to differential it about time to have $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(X)}{\mathrm{d}t}$?

I know that
$$e^{X(t)}=I+X(t)+\frac{X(t)^2}{2!}+\frac{X(t)^3}{3!}+\dots$$
But I dont know how to differential each term $\frac{X(t)^k}{k!}$ about time $t$. Or is there some other method to differential directly $e^{X(t)}$?

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: what does dt mean?

Comment: dt is a very short time range(limit to $0$), just like the dt in a differential equation.

Comment: it could be seen as a constant, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple formula for the derivative of the exponential of a matrix valued function.
However, there is a well known integral representation of the derivative.
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{X(t)} = \int_0^1 e^{\lambda X(t)} \left(\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\right) e^{(1-\lambda)X(t)} d\lambda$$

Look at the wiki page for [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), there are some references for this integral representation.

Answer (score 1):

If $X(t)X'(t)=X'(t)X(t)$, for all $t$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{e}^{X(t)}=\mathrm{e}^{X(t)}\frac{dX(t)}{dt}.
$$
If not, then the above does not hold.

Comment: thank you very much. I dont think that my matrix satisfies that condition.

Comment: another question, if it satisfies your condition, can we have $\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{e}^{X(t)}=\mathrm{e}^{X(t)}\frac{dX(t)}{dt}=\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\mathrm{e}^{X(t)}$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It also holds.